# Get primary key column value of last inserted record in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to capture the primary key value of column based on the last inserted record. Below is the table structure:

```
create table test
(
id varchar(100) not null primary key,
rmain varchar(100),
rpart bigint
);
```

Stored Procedure:

```
Delimiter $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insTest$$
    Create Procedure insTest()
    Begin
    Set @rmain := (select trim(concat('DNB', DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%y'), DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%m'))));

        IF ((trim(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m')) = 01) OR (trim(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m')) = 1)) THEN
            Set @rpart = 1;
        END IF;

        IF ((trim(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m')) != 01) OR (trim(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m')) != 1)) THEN
            Set @rpart := (select coalesce(max(rpart),0) from test) + 1;
        END IF;

        insert into Test (ID, rmain, rpart) values (concat(@rmain,@rpart),@rmain,@rpart);
    End$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Please advice. I checked on `last_insert_ID()` but it works for primary key column with `auto_increment` setting only. Thanks in advance...

Comment: tag your question properly. `mysql` and `tsql` are not same.

Answer (score 2):

Why? What if you get `select max(id)` or if you get `select id from tbl1 order by id desc limit 1`?

See [`Transaction In MySQL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html). Also, set the transaction isolation level to [`READ COMMITTED`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/dynindex-isolevel.html)

```
declare last_id INT;
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO tbl1(id,col1,col2) values(1001,'test','test');
SELECT last_id = id FROM tbl1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
COMMIT;
```

Comment: During concurrent inserts do you think this would work? I want to capture the ID that is inserted by the stored procedure

Comment: Yeah ... sure; why not enclose them in a explicit transaction block?

Comment: how to do that? please advice, a sample code would really help

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO test (a,b,c) values (1,2,3);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

this way you can access the last inserted id

Comment: If you execute more than one statement (on different tables), it always returns the id of the last one.